# I need to change my y-axis scale to an exponential scale and I don't know how?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

```
    plt.scatter(Temperature,Luminosity_Actual)
    ax=plt.gca()
    ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[::-1]) # Reverses the temperature scale so 0 is on the far right
    plt.title('Temperature vs Luminosity')
    plt.xlabel('Temperature')
    plt.ylabel('Luminosty')
    plt.show()
```

The code above is what I have so far (at the end of my function) to create a scatter plot of stars temperature vs their luminosity. Temperature and Luminosity_Actual are both lists. And the plot comes out to look like this: [Practice_HR_diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3trwx.png). 
And I want to set the y-axis to scale exponentially, i.e. from 10^-6 to 10^6. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [semilogy](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy.html).

Here's an example:

```
x = np.linspace(80000, 10000, 40)
y = 1e31*np.exp((x-80000)/10000.)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlim(80000, 10000)
```

[image]

```
plt.semilogy(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlim(80000, 10000)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. What's the 'o' in the third parameter spot do? just curious at this point.  plt.semilogy(x, y, 'o')

Comment: @CazWoodall: the `'o'` is telling plot to show the points as small circles. I only added this in so that the plot would look more like your original. Without it, the points would be connected by a line and you wouldn't see the individual points.